# Appcache and jquery mobile on a CMS powered site?

Tags: cms, mobile, jquery, web-applications, cache

Has anyone used the cache manifest to make a CMS site work offline? I've made a demo with static html files which seems to work fine, so I'm assuming it wouldn't be too hard to achieve the same thing with a CMS.

The way that you tell browsers that files have changed (and so need to be downloaded again) is by adding a comment to the cache manifest file so its byte size changes. I'm not quite sure how to do this with a CMS, but maybe some sort of server cron could run periodically? Personally I'm more interested in having a site that works offline rather than achieving ideal performance, so if the file was modified every hour rather than when content actually changed that would be fine for me.

If anyone has used appcache with a CMS, has anyone done so with jquery mobile at the same time? What I'm after is a fully native feel to a site that's accessible offline, in other words I want to mimic a native App. My static demo does this perfectly with jquery mobile, so again I would have thought this would be achievable in a CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bit over my head but Steve Souders discusses appcahce and the problems he had with it in some of his YouTube videos...no time to look it up now but query 'Fluent,' a conference by O'Reilly media and other videos where Steve Souders discusses performance (be forewarned many are 30 minutes or more...but worth every second).

I don't think it is the 'Fluent' talk, but one of the related videos contains a several minute discussion of appcache...if memory serves.